User is not getting registered
I'm trying to register user using email and password through firebase auth but I'm not getting why it is not getting registered even though I followed doc properly. I guess the problem is in createUserwithEmailandPassoword please look if there is any issue in the code and provide snippet of the solution .
class EmailSignUpFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentEmailSignUpBinding
    private lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel
    private lateinit var name:String
    private lateinit var email:String
    private lateinit var password:String
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = FragmentEmailSignUpBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        homeViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[HomeViewModel::class.java]
        fillForm()
    }

    private fun fillForm() {
        binding.btnEmailSignUp.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.editNameTxt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Please enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } else {
                if (binding.editEmailTxt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Please enter email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                } else {
                    if (binding.editPasswordTxt.text.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Please enter password",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    } else if (binding.editPasswordTxt.text.toString().length < 8) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireActivity(),
                            "Password must have more than 8 characters",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    } else {
                        name=binding.editNameTxt.text.toString()
                        email=binding.editEmailTxt.text.toString()
                        password=binding.editPasswordTxt.text.toString()
                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                            email,
                            password
                        ).addOnCompleteListener(requireActivity()) { task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                homeViewModel.setUserData(
                                    mAuth.currentUser?.uid,
                                    name, 
                                    email,
                                    ""
                                )
                                val home = HomeFragment()
                                val navigationUseCase = switchFragmentUsecase(
                                    requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,
                                    R.id.logFragment
                                )
                                navigationUseCase.navigateToFragment(home)
                            } else {
                                ***Toast.makeText(
                                    requireActivity(),
                                    "Account is not registered",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()***
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

I'm not getting any errors in logcat, but when I'm checking Auth table in Firebase console , it is not showing user creation with this provider and email

Is any of the Toast messages even displayed?

Yes , "Account is not getting registered" is displayed as Toast

Which of those Toasts displays that message? Can you please highlight it in the code?

Ok , I have enclosed that Toast message with *** in the code itself , Please check

@LakshayKadam - Seems like the task is not successful. Worth to check what the status of the task is inside your else block.

@tomerpacific Yes, I also think task is not getting successful

Have you tried to toast the error message and not a hard-coded value?

ohh ok got it ! one thing more , if I sign up with same email id  through email and password provider and google sign in , then duplicate account cannot be created?
